# Is there an -1 at the end of an Inputstream?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am quite new to programming.

While reading the article [*Byte Streams*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) in "Basic I/O" in *The Java Tutorials* by Oracle, I came accross this code:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not understand the condition of the while-loop. Is -1 some kind of sign that the Message is over? Does the FileOutputStream add it at the end?

Thank you all for your attention. I hope you have a wonderfull sylvester.

Comment: See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) — "-1 if the end of the stream is reached"

Comment: What's a 'sylvester', by the way? This is not a common expression in English.  'New Year', perhaps?

Comment: @aguest It is the last day of the year, and it is spelled Silvester.

Comment: Yes, I meant new year. Its "Silvester" in my mothertongue and I thought it is the same in English, because it is the name of a Saint and names do not change that much between languages.

Comment: Much to my surprise, (secular) New Year's Eve in Israel is also "Silvester's Day".  Apparently his birthday was December 31.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, the tool for figuring this out is [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()).

For the 'read' method of FileInputStream:

> public int read()
> throws IOException
>
> Reads a byte of data from this input stream. This method blocks if no input is yet available. Specified by:
> read in class InputStream
>
> Returns: the next byte of data, or -1 if the
> end of the file is reached.

This is definitive.

All standard Java classes are documented in this manner.  In case of uncertainty, a quick check will reassure you.

Answer (score -4):

EDIT: "Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
This exception is mainly used by data input streams, which generally expect a binary file in a specific format, and for which an end of stream is an unusual condition. Most other input streams return a special value on end of stream."

The right way is to catch `EOFException` to find out is it end of file or not, but in tihs case reading chars as `EOF` `-1 is returned` and not `null`, and it's working because there is no char for negative ascii, it's the same to check `while ((c = in.read()) >= 0) {}`, so you can use `!= -1` and it will work.

Comment: There is no `EOFException` thrown to catch.

Comment: if you write while(true) { in.read() }, after eof you will have exception... don't you agree?

Comment: It does not, it simply returns `-1`.

Comment: What you read from an input stream are bytes, not ASCII characters.

Comment: i mean if you read in wile true condition after reading -1, the next read will throw an exception - y it returns -1 in eof but if you don't check it will pass...

Comment: @DeviKhositashvili It will keep returning `-1` to indicate the end of the file, but it will not throw an `EOFException`.

Comment: if you mean only this case, when chars are read, yes - you're right, but in general, you need to catch exception - ill edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Well you didn't make it more clear. You just added to the confusion. 'The right way is to catch `EOFException` *is not true* of all cases, and specifically it isn't true of the OP's case.